# An integral equality involving BesselJ and Hankel function

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

In [this link, page 252](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3596359#opennewwindow), there is an equality of interest, (D.69)

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{x\cdot J_0(x\cdot r)}{x^2-k^2}dx=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{i \cdot\pi \cdot  H_0^{(1)}(k\cdot r)}{2}&\text{Im}(k)>0 \\
\\
 \dfrac{i \cdot\pi \cdot  H_0^{(2)}(k\cdot r)}{2} &\text{Im}(k)<0\\
\end{array}
\right. \tag{D.69}$$

Where $J_0$ is the [BesselJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), $H_0$'s are the [Hankel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions)s respectively.

How to prove the integral equality?

And how to obtain a numerical solution of such integrals? e.g., I tried to let $k=10$ and $r=6$, but found most of the available integral algorithms didnot lead to convergence probably due to the existence of a discontinuity point $x=k$ of the integrand and the improper upper limit.

Comment: If $k$ is non-real, as indicated on the right, there won't be a "discontinuity point" of the integral.

Comment: So the equality holds only when $k$ is not real?